# Volume mounting not working with docker-compose (MacOS)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, mounted-volumes

I am relatively new to Docker and I am attempting to build a single custom image from my Dockerfile using docker-compose.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3

#create a directory 
WORKDIR /home/docker/qts

#copy the dependencies file
COPY ./requirements.txt .

#install necessary packages
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

#Expose ports
EXPOSE 5000
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  pyimg:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - $HOME/Documents/qts:/home/docker/qts
```

**My issue**

Running `docker-compose build` gives me no errors. When I execute `docker run -it <image_name> bash` and navigate into the directory /home/docker/qts, the directory does not mirror the local directory.

A `docker inspect` also shows that the volumes are not mounted (and that the ports that I have exposed have also not been mapped to the local ports!) What am I missing here?

Thank you for your input.

```
[
    {
        "Id": "cc506e95df8788349090b310bfa6965b56dbb9e218efe4a9024eb2f502a2d2f2",
        "Created": "2021-02-27T14:44:14.9474339Z",
        "Path": "bash",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 2712,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2021-02-27T14:44:15.2955648Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:332985fd4830584b0356f0bf28500f5b951f7ae1fb0e0b5d774c264e28a900e3",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/cc506e95df8788349090b310bfa6965b56dbb9e218efe4a9024eb2f502a2d2f2/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/cc506e95df8788349090b310bfa6965b56dbb9e218efe4a9024eb2f502a2d2f2/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/cc506e95df8788349090b310bfa6965b56dbb9e218efe4a9024eb2f502a2d2f2/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/cc506e95df8788349090b310bfa6965b56dbb9e218efe4a9024eb2f502a2d2f2/cc506e95df8788349090b310bfa6965b56dbb9e218efe4a9024eb2f502a2d2f2-json.log",
        "Name": "/determined_aryabhata",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a802a922e08dd98e4dcebea8253d2457393aa5380ba31698087ebab7c20c7420-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7fd10d3a3749cfbcfb8ba4bffbe4d5ec9b70c0244f18d8bcbc10e50526fa2836/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a951e71a24b2c5635f34fbac57fe02e902ffa55928854bd63918c3a0eac8bd6a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/67defaf9804e20dbe3bb9b06a68301b527cebf5ad15103d129b564b4678f65eb/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7e88aebe633878bdd3fe36eb842259d1e898f64fd6937a47ac7b32cb77958fe0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/61c831913d4448f0efa8b78852181b45c993aa6d5d6b1d7b01e85f936121ab4d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dc34279b6529ec9d0123de5a46520de90775fe9ad0d87f8e8a572085df7bf3d3/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a802a922e08dd98e4dcebea8253d2457393aa5380ba31698087ebab7c20c7420/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a802a922e08dd98e4dcebea8253d2457393aa5380ba31698087ebab7c20c7420/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a802a922e08dd98e4dcebea8253d2457393aa5380ba31698087ebab7c20c7420/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "cc506e95df87",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": true,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5000/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": true,
            "OpenStdin": true,
            "StdinOnce": true,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
```

Comment: `docker run` doesn't look at `docker-compose.yml` at all; if you want to use that file, you need `docker-compose` commands.

Answer (score -1):

You can not see with docker run you can check like below;

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  pyimg:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - $HOME/Documents/qts:/home/docker/qts
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - sleep 60
```

With docker ps find your container id than;

```
docker exec -it ID /bin/bash
```

And

```
ls
```